# What are the resources needed for each web application on SharePoint 2013?

Tags: sharepoint-2013

Dears,

We have a SharePoint Server with 16 GB RAM. and we need to create 5 web applications on it.

Would this be suitable or not?

In other words, What are the resources needed for one Web application?

Comment: I'm  sorry, but I don't see how this relates to programming?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is unrelated to programming.

Comment: I have tagged the post with SharePoint 2013, not programming?

Answer (score 0):

You can check a lot of information regarding the same here:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/install/software-boundaries-and-limits

Hope you find it useful.

Regards,
Purushottam

Comment: Thank you, it helps